# Compare a source audio and microphone input based on intonation

Tags: audio, comparison

I am working on a language learning app geared toward intermediate learners. One of the thing I want to do is to help learners with intonation.

**My idea is to:

1. play an audio with its pitch contour
2. as learners shadow the audio, display the pitch contour of the microphone input on top of the audio pitch contour as feedback to user
3. compare the microphone input with the audio to product a score.**

I'm not interested in pronunciation or voice recognition - they could be whistling for all I care, as long as the intonation is good.

I've done a bit of online research (mostly `pitch contour` and `intonation` comparison keywords) and these are the closest I have found:.

1. https://github.com/danafallon/IntonationCoach
2. https://github.com/melizalab/chirp

Based on my search there isn't anything ready-made out there but if anyone can point out what other keywords to search for, that would be appreciated.